# How to display a complete string that is passed to another ajax page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to ajax, I dont know how i can check the values that are passed to another page in ajax, Actually i want to confirm the values passed to another page using alert.
here is the variable which i want to check with alert

`data: 'user='+user_id+'&project='+project+'&date from='+date_from+'&date to='+date_to+'&stat='+status+'&leave_type='+leave_type,`

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, if you wanna verify the data that has been posted, you can use [`var_dump()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) function.

```
<?php
    var_dump($_REQUEST);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is a call to the server and a response from the server happening without a page reload.  There is no second page that your ajax request is making a call too.  If you want to confirm the variables passed to the server side, you can check the network tab in the developer console of your browser.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools